# Group wise Last Null Values with specific condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given Data

```
ID  X_ST    Y_ST    STATUS_FLAG T_DATE  Last Tran   HOURDIFF
42015   0   2   3   1/1/2017 0:00   1/1/2017 23:49  NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/2/2017 0:00   1/2/2017 23:49  NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/3/2017 0:00   1/3/2017 23:49  NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/4/2017 0:00   1/4/2017 23:49  NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/5/2017 0:00   1/5/2017 23:49  NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/6/2017 0:00   1/6/2017 20:49  NULL
42015   0   3   1   1/6/2017 0:00   1/6/2017 21:46  NULL
42015   1   0   2   1/9/2017 0:00   1/9/2017 23:49  9.7
42015   1   0   2   1/10/2017 0:00  1/10/2017 22:49 11.7
42015   0   2   3   1/10/2017 0:00  1/10/2017 23:49 11.7
42015   1   0   2   1/11/2017 0:00  1/11/2017 22:49 10.5
42015   0   2   3   1/11/2017 0:00  1/11/2017 23:49 10.5
42015   1   0   2   1/12/2017 0:00  1/12/2017 20:49 9.3
42015   0   2   3   1/12/2017 0:00  1/12/2017 23:49 9.3
42015   1   0   2   1/13/2017 0:00  1/13/2017 13:49 1.2
42015   0   2   3   1/13/2017 0:00  1/13/2017 22:49 1.2
42015   0   2   3   1/14/2017 0:00  1/14/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/15/2017 0:00  1/15/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/16/2017 0:00  1/16/2017 23:49 0.2
42015   0   2   3   1/17/2017 0:00  1/17/2017 23:49 0.7
42015   0   2   3   1/18/2017 0:00  1/18/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/19/2017 0:00  1/19/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/20/2017 0:00  1/20/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/21/2017 0:00  1/21/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/22/2017 0:00  1/22/2017 23:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/23/2017 0:00  1/23/2017 20:49 NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/24/2017 0:00  1/24/2017 21:49 NULL
42015   0   3   1   1/24/2017 0:00  1/24/2017 22:34 NULL
```

Desired Data

```
ID  X_ST    Y_ST    STATUS_FLAG T_DATE  Last Tran   HOURDIFF    DAYS
42015   0   2   3   1/1/2017 0:00   1/1/2017 23:49  NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/2/2017 0:00   1/2/2017 23:49  NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/3/2017 0:00   1/3/2017 23:49  NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/4/2017 0:00   1/4/2017 23:49  NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/5/2017 0:00   1/5/2017 23:49  NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/6/2017 0:00   1/6/2017 20:49  NULL    NULL
42015   0   3   1   1/6/2017 0:00   1/6/2017 21:46  NULL    **6**
42015   1   0   2   1/9/2017 0:00   1/9/2017 23:49  9.7    NULL
42015   1   0   2   1/10/2017 0:00  1/10/2017 22:49 11.7    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/10/2017 0:00  1/10/2017 23:49 11.7    NULL
42015   1   0   2   1/11/2017 0:00  1/11/2017 22:49 10.5    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/11/2017 0:00  1/11/2017 23:49 10.5    NULL
42015   1   0   2   1/12/2017 0:00  1/12/2017 20:49 9.3     NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/12/2017 0:00  1/12/2017 23:49 9.3     NULL
42015   1   0   2   1/13/2017 0:00  1/13/2017 13:49 1.2     NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/13/2017 0:00  1/13/2017 22:49 1.2     NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/14/2017 0:00  1/14/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/15/2017 0:00  1/15/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/16/2017 0:00  1/16/2017 23:49 0.2     NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/17/2017 0:00  1/17/2017 23:49 0.7     NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/18/2017 0:00  1/18/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/19/2017 0:00  1/19/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/20/2017 0:00  1/20/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/21/2017 0:00  1/21/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/22/2017 0:00  1/22/2017 23:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/23/2017 0:00  1/23/2017 20:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   2   3   1/24/2017 0:00  1/24/2017 21:49 NULL    NULL
42015   0   3   1   1/24/2017 0:00  1/24/2017 22:34 NULL    **7**
```

Here I am focusing only on STATUS_FLAG = 1 and 3.
When Status flag is 1 then I need to check previous all the status_flag = 3 and HOUR DIFF must be NULL., then I want to count of all NULL records.

Please see the desired result with column **Days**.

please find the attached image.enter image description here

Any help would be appreciable.
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Thanks
Saumil Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is for sure not the most effective way of doing this, but using recursive common table expression can solve this. Here is the full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [ID] INT
    ,[X_ST] BIT
    ,[Y_ST] TINYINT
    ,[STATUS_FLAG] TINYINT
    ,[T_DATE] DATETIME2
    ,[Last Tran] DATETIME2
    ,[HOURDIFF] DECIMAL(9,1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [X_ST], [Y_ST], [STATUS_FLAG], [T_DATE], [Last Tran], [HOURDIFF])
VALUES   (42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/1/2017 0:00', '1/1/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/2/2017 0:00', '1/2/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/3/2017 0:00', '1/3/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/4/2017 0:00', '1/4/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/5/2017 0:00', '1/5/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/6/2017 0:00', '1/6/2017 20:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 3, 1, '1/6/2017 0:00', '1/6/2017 21:46', NULL)
        ,(42015, 1, 0, 2, '1/9/2017 0:00', '1/9/2017 23:49', 9.7)
        ,(42015, 1, 0, 2, '1/10/2017 0:00', '1/10/2017 22:49', 11.7)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/10/2017 0:00', '1/10/2017 23:49', 11.7)
        ,(42015, 1, 0, 2, '1/11/2017 0:00', '1/11/2017 22:49', 10.5)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/11/2017 0:00', '1/11/2017 23:49', 10.5)
        ,(42015, 1, 0, 2, '1/12/2017 0:00', '1/12/2017 20:49', 9.3)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/12/2017 0:00', '1/12/2017 23:49', 9.3)
        ,(42015, 1, 0, 2, '1/13/2017 0:00', '1/13/2017 13:49', 1.2)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/13/2017 0:00', '1/13/2017 22:49', 1.2)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/14/2017 0:00', '1/14/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/15/2017 0:00', '1/15/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/16/2017 0:00', '1/16/2017 23:49', 0.2)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/17/2017 0:00', '1/17/2017 23:49', 0.7)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/18/2017 0:00', '1/18/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/19/2017 0:00', '1/19/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/20/2017 0:00', '1/20/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/21/2017 0:00', '1/21/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/22/2017 0:00', '1/22/2017 23:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/23/2017 0:00', '1/23/2017 20:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 2, 3, '1/24/2017 0:00', '1/24/2017 21:49', NULL)
        ,(42015, 0, 3, 1, '1/24/2017 0:00', '1/24/2017 22:34', NULL);

WITH DataSourceRaw AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [T_DATE] ASC, [Last Tran] ASC) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM @DataSource
), RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [RowNumber], [RowNumber] AS [GroupID], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM DataSourceRaw
    WHERE [STATUS_FLAG] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.[RowNumber], R.[RowNumber] + R.[Level], [Level] + 1
    FROM RecursiveDataSource R
    INNER JOIN DataSourceRaw C
        ON R.[RowNumber] = C.[RowNumber] + 1
    WHERE C.[STATUS_FLAG] = 3
        AND C.[HOURDIFF] IS NULL
)
SELECT DSR.*
      ,IIF(DSR.[STATUS_FLAG] = 1, DS.[Days] -1, NULL) AS [Days]
FROM DataSourceRaw DSR
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM RecursiveDataSource
    WHERE DSR.[RowNumber]  = [GroupID]
) DS ([Days])
ORDER BY [T_DATE] ASC, [Last Tran] ASC;
```

[image]

The solution is pretty simple:

1. create a row number for each row; we need to have the data sorted and we are going to use this row ID in order to perform faster joins in the recursive part
2. create a recursive CTE - the anchor part is composed by all rows with `[STATUS_FLAG] = 1`; then for each of them we are getting all `smaller` rows which have no value for the `HOURDIFF` column
3. then get all the initial data and count the rows for each row with `[STATUS_FLAG] = 1`

Few notes:

- in the recursive CTE we are using only part of the columns
- in the recursive CTE we are using a level column in order to match which rows to which group belongs

---

Here is the code with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
WITH DataSourceRaw AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [T_DATE] ASC, [Last Tran] ASC) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM @DataSource
), RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [RowNumber], [RowNumber] AS [GroupID], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM DataSourceRaw
    WHERE [STATUS_FLAG] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.[RowNumber], R.[RowNumber] + R.[Level], [Level] + 1
    FROM RecursiveDataSource R
    INNER JOIN DataSourceRaw C
        ON R.[RowNumber] = C.[RowNumber] + 1
    WHERE C.[STATUS_FLAG] = 3
        AND C.[HOURDIFF] IS NULL
)
SELECT DSR.*
      ,IIF(DSR.[STATUS_FLAG] = 1, DS.[Days] -1, NULL) AS [Days]
FROM DataSourceRaw DSR
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [GroupID]
          ,COUNT(*)
    FROM RecursiveDataSource
    GROUP BY [GroupID]
) DS ([GroupID], [Days])
    ON DSR.[RowNumber] = DS.[GroupID]
ORDER BY [T_DATE] ASC, [Last Tran] ASC;
```

Comment: Hi Gotqn, Thanks for the great help. This code is working fine in Sql server.
Now, I have to do this functionality in IBM Netezza tool(Aginity Workbench) and I am not able to find CROSS APPLY function in Netezza. Could you please help me in that??

Comment: @SaumilShah Instead of using `CROSS APPLY` you can simply use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: ,I am still facing error and not exactly understand how data is join with other table. I've never used CROSS_APPLY so not understand how I achieve this data using LEFT_JOIN. Could you please add the LEFT_JOIN code so I can understand this in easy way?

Comment: @SaumilShah Sure, check the edit. Let me know if anything is not OK. You can find more about `CROSS APPLY` in the official documentation. It is a powerful clause. Check it for sure.